# Rails routes generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm trying to just configure my routes in my rails, but it keeps on coming up with a `"."` instead of the traditional `"/"` divider in the URL, like so: `localhost3000/media.1`?

routes.rb

```
 Mediastuff::Application.routes.draw do

  get "media" => "media#index"
  get "media/:id" => "media#show", as: "media_show"


end
```

Media controller.

```
    class MediaController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @medias = Media.all
    end

    def show
        @media = Media.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

index.html.erb.

```
<header>
  <h2><%= link_to(media.title, media_path(media)) %></h2>
</header>
<p>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does anyone know why the shortcut <%= link_to(media.title, media)%> line returns - undefined method `medium_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000101d98530>:0x000001020d4ff0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<%= link_to(media.title, media_show_path(media)) %>`, or just `<%= link_to(media.title, media) %>`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but the synatactic sugar line dosen't, it says undefined method `medium_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000101d98530>:0x000001020d4ff0> ??

Answer (score 2):

Because you have written `as` in your root then your path helper is changed `get "media/:id" => "media#show", as: "media_show"`

so use following:

```
<header>
  <h2><%= link_to(media.title, media_show_path(media)) %></h2>
</header>
<p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better doing this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :media, only: [:show, :index]
```

...and then using Uandl's answer